# Casting defaults.objectForKey to Array<(String,Double)>

Tags: swift, casting

I am attempted to cast an object from NSUserdefault as a array with a tuple, but it is not conforming to protocol

```
// works
var records: String
records = defaults.objectForKey("friend_records") as String ?? ""

// works with warning 
var records: Array<String>?
records = defaults.objectForKey("friend_records") as Array<String> ?? []

// does not conform to protocol
var records: Array<(String, Double)>?
records = defaults.objectForKey("friend_records") as Array<(String, Double)> ?? []
```

What is the explanation and the solution?

Comment: what version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store an array of tuples in `NSUserDefaults`. `NSUserDefaults` can only store property list data, which means NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. `[(String, Double)]` is not convertible to `NSArray`, so it can't be stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

There are several ways to deal with this.

If order doesn't matter and the strings are unique, then you could convert this to a `[String:Double]` dictionary.

You could split up the strings and doubles into two arrays and store them separately (see the `zip` command for an easy way to put them back together; unfortunately Swift doesn't have an `unzip` equivalent).

You could convert these to JSON and store a `[String]`.

You could make some other simple data format like "mystring:123.45" and store it as a `[String]`.

You could move these tuples into a simple data object. Most uses of tuples are better implemented as a data object anyway (tuples can be very error prone). You could then implement `NSCoding` on the data object, and serialize it to an `NSData`. This is the generic approach to storing non-propertylist stuff in `NSUserDefaults`.